# How to await method in PropertyValidator's overridden IsValid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to use my Data Repository in PropertyValidator class. The problem is that method in the Repository is async... and I can't see `IsValidAsync` to override.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentValidation.Validators;
using AccountApi.Domain.Repositories;

namespace AccountApi.Domain.Validators
{
    public class UserInputValidator<TElement> : PropertyValidator
    {
        private IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public UserInputValidator(IUserRepository userRepository)
            : base("{Message}.")
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
            var id = (int)context.PropertyValue;
            var user = await _userRepository.GetById(id); // <--- HERE is the problem  

            // ..... 

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change to this:

```
protected override async Task<bool> IsValidAsync(PropertyValidatorContext context)
```

... but it doesn't work as well. There is no `IsValidAsync` to override.

Is it possible to use `async` methods inside PropertyValidator?

Answer (score 3):

You're sort of on the right track.

Yes, you do overload the `PropertyValidator` method `protected virtual async Task<bool> IsValidAsync(PropertyValidatorContext context, CancellationToken cancellation)`

However you need to use the `validator.ValidateAsync(objectToValidate)` method to use it.

> If your validator contains asynchronous validators or asynchronous
>   conditions, it’s important that you always call ValidateAsync on your
>   validator and never Validate. If you call Validate, then your
>   asynchronous rules will be run synchronously, which is not desirable.

[Source](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html)

Additionally refer to the following [issue](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/999) where Jeremy suggests:

- Also overloading the `ShouldValidateAsync` method; **or better still**
- Use the `AsyncValidatorBase` rather than `PropertyValidator` which handles the `ShouldValidateAsync` overload for you

See the following if you want to see a [working solution](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question60871574) of an async property validator.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use async methods inside PropertyValidator?

You could press F12 on `PropertyValidator` in vs to see its methods.

```
public abstract class PropertyValidator : IPropertyValidator
{
    protected PropertyValidator(IStringSource errorMessageSource);
    protected PropertyValidator(string errorMessage);
    [Obsolete("This constructor will be removed in FluentValidation 9.0. Use the overload that takes an IStringSource instead, passing in a LazyStringSource: PropertyValidator(new LazyStringSource(ctx => MyResourceClass.MyResourceName))")]
    protected PropertyValidator(string errorMessageResourceName, Type errorMessageResourceType);

    public PropertyValidatorOptions Options { get; }

    public virtual bool ShouldValidateAsync(ValidationContext context);
    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> Validate(PropertyValidatorContext context);
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<ValidateAsync>d__7))]
    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<ValidationFailure>> ValidateAsync(PropertyValidatorContext context, CancellationToken cancellation);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates an error validation result for this validator.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   context:
    //     The validator context
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Returns an error validation result.
    protected virtual ValidationFailure CreateValidationError(PropertyValidatorContext context);
    protected abstract bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context);
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<IsValidAsync>d__10))]
    protected virtual Task<bool> IsValidAsync(PropertyValidatorContext context, CancellationToken cancellation);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Prepares the FluentValidation.Internal.MessageFormatter of context for an upcoming
    //     FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   context:
    //     The validator context
    protected virtual void PrepareMessageFormatterForValidationError(PropertyValidatorContext context);
}
```

So,try to use

```
protected override async Task<bool> IsValidAsync(PropertyValidatorContext context, CancellationToken cancellation)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Just use "AsyncPropertyValidator" or "AsyncPropertyValidator<T, type>"

In your case it will be like

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentValidation.Validators;
using AccountApi.Domain.Repositories;
    
namespace AccountApi.Domain.Validators
{
    public class UserInputValidator<TElement> : AsyncPropertyValidator
    {
        private IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public UserInputValidator(IUserRepository userRepository)
            : base("{Message}.")
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

         public override async Task<bool> IsValidAsync(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
            var id = (int)context.PropertyValue;
            var user = await _userRepository.GetById(id);

            // .. 

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```